# Rearrange specific cell according to the tag in front

Tags: r, dplyr

I work in R and my data looks like the following,  Right now they are 3 columns of data in df. 
Is there any way to rearrange the columns by the tag in front, namely H, D & A? 
So far I can't see any patterns of the wrong arrangement...but I would like to rearrange it for over 1000 rows.

```
 H                   A               D
H":"100@1.68"   A:"100@4.35"    D:"100@3.35"
H":"100@2.33"   D:"100@3.20"    A:"100@2.62"
A":"100@2.25"   D:"100@3.15"    H:"100@2.78"
H":"100@2.80"   D:"100@3.25"    A:"100@2.18"
D":"100@3.05"   A:"100@3.40"    H:"100@2.00"
H":"100@2.30"   A:"100@2.90"    D:"100@2.92"
D":"100@3.05"   H:"100@2.25"    A:"100@2.85"
```

Comment: Just to be clear, rearrange like with every "H" tag under column H, every "A" under column A ecc. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
# example data
df = read.table(text = "
H                   A               D
H:100@1.68   A:100@4.35    D:100@3.35
H:100@2.33   D:100@3.20    A:100@2.62
A:100@2.25   D:100@3.15    H:100@2.78
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather() %>%                            # reshape data
  group_by(key = substr(value,1,1)) %>%   # update column names based on first character
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%       # add row id (useful for reshaping again)
  spread(key, value) %>%                  # reshape data
  select(-row_id)                         # remove column

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   A          D          H         
#   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 A:100@2.25 D:100@3.20 H:100@1.68
# 2 A:100@4.35 D:100@3.15 H:100@2.33
# 3 A:100@2.62 D:100@3.35 H:100@2.78
```

Comment: if all the elements elements are of the same size, ie in your case we have 3A,3H and 3D then you can simply do `data.frame(array(sort(unlist(df)),dim(df)))`